# Effect of Vinculum(bar) over multiplication sign

Tags: algebra-precalculus, combinations

I know that when there is a vinculum(bar) over two numbers,it changes of sign of plus into minus and vice versa
But
What is the effect of a vinculum(bar) over two numbers when those numbers have multiply or divide sign in between them?? Does it changes multiply into divide and vice versa?

Comment: Personally I'm not quite sure what you're talking about - are you thinking about complex conjugates, where $\overline{x + iy} \equiv x - iy$? (for given values of $x$, $y$, of course)

Comment: One other context comes to mind besides complex number conjugates.  Its frequently seen in Boolean logic, digital circuitry equations, etc., where it is treated as a logical negation, e.g. DeMorgans Rule: $\overline{A+B} = \overline{A}\cdot\overline{B}$

Comment: In set theory $\overline{S}$ could be used to represent the complement, $\mathcal{U}\setminus S$, of the set $S$. Ive seen this notation before though not often; I favor $S'$ or $S^{c}$.

Comment: In topology $\overline{U}$ might represent the closure of the set $U$. Little off topic, but interestingly notation is not always consistent; something like $U'$ in topology might represent the set of accumulation points of $U$, rather than the set complement.

Comment: Could you update your post with a little more detail, perhaps explain the context you've seen the notation used? Or write the math out, at least.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your talking about expression that include the symbols $\pm$ and $\mp$. A common example of this notation appear in the sum and difference formulas for cosine, which are sometimes written as
$$
\cos(A \pm B) = \cos A \cos B  \mp  \sin A \sin B
$$
as a shorthand for
$$
\cos(A + B) = \cos A \cos B  −  \sin A \sin B\\
\cos(A - B) = \cos A \cos B  +  \sin A \sin B
$$

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking if this convention carries over to multiplication and division so that, for example, the symbols $\overline\times$ and $\underline{\times}$ might indicate alternating between the multiplication and division in the same way as shown above. I personally have never such notation used. I think it is far more likely that whatever text you found these symbols in is simplify using them to denote a unique operator, in which case I'd advise looking for how the author defines these symbols.

For a more general discussion of common uses of overline/viculum notation, you may wish to see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline#Math_and_science) on the topic.